# How to update cell Data using Hibernate SQL query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have a table 'users', with many columns, among them two are 'Username' and 'Password'
username is primary key column

I want to update password for a username. here is my code it is working fine (no error or exception) but not updating password.

I am new to Hibernate and do not know much of its syntax. please help me

```
 String query = "UPDATE users SET Password = '"+ newPassword +"' WHERE Username = '"+ login.getUsername() + "'";

 session.createSQLQuery(query);
```

login.getUsername() is getting required username correctly

Rest of code is working fine problem is in above code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have just created a query, but you haven't executed it:

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);
sqlQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Note that

- you should use named parameters instead of concatenating parameters. This would prevent SQL injection attacks, or simply errors when the password or user name contains `'`
- in Hibernate, you typically do such simple operations with:

-

```
User u = session.get(User.class, userName);
u.setPassword(newPassword);
```

Comment: can i use 2nd approach to update single cell in a row, because i tried it but hibernate make all others cells to null

Comment: Yes, you can. If it sets other cells to null, it means you have done something other than the above.

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot the execute method, them:

```
String query = "UPDATE users SET Password = '"+ newPassword +"' WHERE Username = '"+            login.getUsername() + "'";
try {
    s.getTransaction().begin();
    s.createSQLQuery(query).executeUpdate();
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
}
catch (HibernateException erro){
    s.getTransaction().rollback();
    s.close();
}
```

I strongly advise you not to use concatenating parameters in order to prevent SQL injection attacks, or simply errors that depends of your Strings. Take a look at [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) and [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone like me

If we do a update directly for one field it will set all other fields to their default values.

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
User user = new User();
user.password("xxxxx");
session.update(user);
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

above code sets all other fields to thier default values. so to avoid this we have to fetch the object from the table and then modify it and perform update operation.

We can either use `session.load` or `session.get` to fetch the object and update it.

**code**:

```
User u = session.load(User.class, userName);
u.setPassword(newPassword);
```

or

```
User u = session.get(User.class, userName);
u.setPassword(newPassword);
```

and then need to perform `session.update(user)`

full code:

```
        SessionFactory factory = hibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        User user = session.load(User.class, username);
        user.setPassword("xxxxxx");
        session.update(user);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
```